# implement declaration and uiapplication delegate

Tags: square-connect

New to iOS development so I'm a little confused on this part of implement the point of sale sdk

Usage

Swift

Import Declaration: import SquarePointOfSaleSDK

```
// Replace with your app's URL scheme.
let yourCallbackURL = URL(string: "your-url-scheme://")!

// Your client ID is the same as your Square Application ID.
// Note: You only need to set your client ID once, before creating your first request.
SCCAPIRequest.setClientID("YOUR_CLIENT_ID")

do {
    // Specify the amount of money to charge.
    let money = try SCCMoney(amountCents: 100, currencyCode: "USD")

    // Create the request.
    let apiRequest =
        try SCCAPIRequest(
            callbackURL: yourCallbackURL,
            amount: money,
            userInfoString: nil,
            merchantID: nil,
            notes: "Coffee",
            customerID: nil,
            supportedTenderTypes: .all,
            clearsDefaultFees: false,
            returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment: false
        )

    // Open Point of Sale to complete the payment.
    try SCCAPIConnection.perform(apiRequest)

} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Finally, implement the UIApplication delegate method as follows:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    guard let sourceApplication = options[.sourceApplication] as? String,
        sourceApplication.hasPrefix("com.squareup.square") else {
        return false
    }

    do {
        let response = try SCCAPIResponse(responseURL: url)

        if let error = response.error {
            // Handle a failed request.
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            // Handle a successful request.
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        // Handle unexpected errors.
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return true
}
```

I'm a little confused where I put these respective pieces of code. My best guess is that the UIApplication delegate goes into AppDelegate.swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `client ID` in the `appDidFinishLaunching` method in `AppDelegate` since it only needs to be set once.

The code that creates and executes the API request can go in whatever view controller you'd like to use to initiate the payment.

You are correct, the last method should be added to your `AppDelegate`.